How to add default outlook signature in VBA?
I've searched on the internet for answers, and in theory it should work with the code below, but for some reason i get an error on the .HTMLBody = Emailbody & .HTMLBody line. Any idea why?
Sub mailTCB()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim EmailAddresses As String
    Dim EmailCC As String
    Dim EmailSubject As String
    Dim AttachmentPath As String
    Dim Emailbody As String
    Dim SenderEmail As String
    Dim I As Long
    
    ' Concatenate email addresses into a single string
    EmailAddresses = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(";", True, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Range("B3:B50"))
    EmailCC = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(";", True, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Range("F3:F10"))
    
    ' Set email subject
    EmailSubject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Range("C3").Value
    
    ' Set email body
    Emailbody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Range("D3").Value & "<br><br>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Range("D4").Value & "<br><br>" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Range("D5").Value
             
    
    ' Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Add attachments from column C starting at cell E3 until a blank cell
    I = 3
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Cells(I, 5).Value)
        AttachmentPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCB").Cells(I, 5).Value
        OutlookMail.Attachments.Add AttachmentPath
        I = I + 1
    Loop

    ' Set email properties
    With OutlookMail
        .Display
        .To = EmailAddresses
        .CC = EmailCC
        .Subject = EmailSubject
        .HTMLBody = Emailbody & .HTMLBody
        .Display
    End With
    
    ' Release Outlook objects from memory
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

The thing is this works on one computer, but doesn't on another one.

i get an error on the .HTMLBody = Emailbody & .HTMLBody line. Any details on that?

Comment .HTMLBody = Emailbody & .HTMLBody to prove you have the signature. The question is how to add Emailbody to .HTMLBody. See problem with my outlook signature outlook with VBA

Alternatives Inserting Signature into Outlook email from Excel VBA. Fix indiscriminate use of On Error Resume Next if necessary.

You cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a well-formed HTML back. Emailbody variable needs to be merged inside the HTMLBody, e.g. inserted after the <body> tag.
